# Calling a Generic Method from BaseEntity on unknown object

Tags: c#, generics

this is what I do if I know the type;

```
TypeA.Get<TypeA>(Id).Delete();
```

and what I am trying to do is this;

```
object ObjectA;

(BaseEntity<typeof(ObjectA)>).Get<(BaseEntity<typeof(ObjectA)>)>(Id).Delete();
```

which didn't work, any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: `Get` is a static method, right?

Comment: Yes Its static method

Comment: Alright, my code should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- use reflection to call both `Get` and `Delete` methods, or:
- use reflection to call `Get` and `dynamic` to invoke `Delete`

Since you're giving up static typing either way, I'd go with the 2nd option for simplicity.

```
var typeA = objectA.GetType();
var fEntityType = typeof(FEntity<>).MakeGenericType(typeA);

var getMethod = fEntityType.GetMethod("Get").MakeGenericMethod(typeA);

dynamic result = getMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]{ Id });

result.Delete();
```

Comment: typeA.GetMethod("Get") is null, maybe Its because method from baseentity?

Comment: @Mert No, `GetMethod` should retrieve all methods declared in that class and any derived types. Is `Get` not public? Is it internal or something?

Comment: public static FReturn<T> Get<T>(Guid uId) where T : new();

Comment: this is base entity; "public class BaseEntity<T> : FEntityObject<T> where T : FEntityObject<T>, new()" and Get method under FEntityObject

Comment: when I call typeA.GetMethods() I can see virtual methods but not static ones.

Comment: @Mert yeah, that's the problem, I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: I solved the method problem by doing typeA.BaseType.BaseType.GetMethod("Get") now trying to fit in Guid Id to object Array

Comment: Id doesn't accept unless Its reference type. I have guid which doesn't work but string works which doesn't suit my problem :)

Comment: @Mert Ive updated my answer, you should be able to retrieve the `Get` method now. That's better than calling `BaseType` twice.

Comment: About your second problem..so the `Get` method takes a `Guid` as parameter right? Whats happening, do you get an exception?

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Guid[]' to 'object[]'

Comment: new object[] { Id } looks solved that problem. result.Delete getting error now I am checking :)

Comment: @Mert Read my mind, I just updated the answer. With reference types, you can just declare `new[]{}`, which will be evaluated to `string[]`, which is covariantly convertable to an `object[]`. However, array covariance doesnt work for value types, so you need to declare an `object[]` instead.

Comment: yeah last one is my framework specific problem Its working :) thank you for your effort!